# Local Notifications Still there after removing the application from device

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, ios6, uilocalnotification

How can we remove the Local Notifications with removing the application from the device. I have seen once we have set local notification with application and remove the application from device and reinstalling the application showing local notification with previous version data there. Presently I am using IOS 6. Please Suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a day the notifications should go away.  If you uninstall the application and move the clock a day forward it should have the same effect.

Comment: I think this will be there till its firedate is not passed.

Comment: The system clears out push related stuff a day or so after the application registered for the push notification goes away.  Fire date should have nothing to do with it, since there is no more application to fire against.

Comment: ok, can we remove all the notifications when user will remove the application from device.

Comment: The system will do that for you.  You are not notified when the application is deleted, there is nothing you can do.